# why the css property doesn't work with mixin?

Tags: css, scss-mixins

This is the mixin code for the adaptive font.
Why does the CSS property issue an invalid value?

```
@mixin adaptiv-font($pcSize, $mobSize){
$addSize: $pcSize - $mobSize;
$addMobSize: $addSize + $addSize * 0.7;
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: calc(#{$mobSize + px} + #{$addMobSize} * ((100vw - 320px) / #{$maxWidth}));
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: calc(#{$mobSize + px} + #{$addSize} * (100vw / #{$maxWidth}));
}  
}
```

[image: A picture of my problem.]

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#syntax):

> `/` Division. The right-hand side must be a [`<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number).

So your `#{$maxWidth}` should not include any units - not `1360px` but `1360`